# Loading multiple AdMob videos

Tags: java, android, admob, rewardedvideoad

For demonstration purposes, the app has one activity that simply offers this:
[image]

You click a button, view a rewarded video, and you are rewarded with whatever.

**The Problem**

How can I load the videos? From what I have seen you can only call `mAd.loadAd()` once. There are 3 videos, each with their own AD UNIT ID. Each ad unit can have its own listener, but only one video loads so it doesn't matter...

**When trying to load multiple videos**

For example:

```
mAd1.loadAd("AD_UNIT_1", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
mAd2.loadAd("AD_UNIT_2", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
mAd3.loadAd("AD_UNIT_3", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

results in only the last video being loaded and this in log:

`W/Ads: Loading already in progress, saving this object for future refreshes.`

**onCreate()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAd1 = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd2 = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd3 = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

    listeners...

    mAd1.loadAd() etc
}
```

Thank you for your help

*Edit: It's clear I am thinking about this problem wrong. I have 5+ ad zones that each will play a rewarded video and give a different reward (for example, one gives coins, one gives a level up, and so on..). There is no reason to load 5 videos. I should load one in `onCreate()`, so it's ready when needed, then load it again after the item is rewarded so it's ready for next time.*

*So the question remains, if there is just the one video, and thus one ad zone, being loaded `onCreate()` then how can I track what reward to give?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a simple solution...

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
            switch(Constants.currentAd) {
                case("REWARD1"):
                    //do something
                    Constants.currentAd = "";
                    break;

                case("REWARD2"):
                    //do something
                    Constants.currentAd = "";
                    break;

                case("REWARD3"):
                    //do something
                    Constants.currentAd = "";
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

   mAd.loadAd("REWARDED_VIDEO_UNIT_ID", new AdRequest.Builder().build());
}

public void showRewardedVideo() {
        if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.show();
        }
    }
```

**Constants.java**

```
public class Constants {
    public static String currentAd = "";
}
```

**Showing the ad after button click**

```
rewardButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Constants.currentAd = "REWARD1";
                dismiss();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).showRewardedVideo();
            }
        });
```

REWARDED_VIDEO_UNIT_ID is one ad unit for rewarded video in AdMob...remove the rest. No need for other units, you can track whatever you like in the listener.

Comment: it makes no sense if there is only one unit id for all videos. Could you please prove it?

Answer (score 0):

Other simple soluction...

**AbstractRewardVideo.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractRewardVideo {
    private RewardedVideoAd mAd;
    private String adId = "ca-app-pub...";
    private Activity activity;

    abstract protected RewardedVideoAdListener getListener();

    public void init(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(activity);
        setAdId(adId);
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    public Activity getActivity(){
        return this.activity;
    }

    public void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mAd.loadAd(adId, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    public void showVideo(){
        setListener(getListener());
        if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
            mAd.show();
        } else {
            Utils.exibirToast("Don't loaded!");
        }
    }

    public void setAdId(@NonNull String id){
        this.adId = id;
    }

    public void setListener(RewardedVideoAdListener listener){
        mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(listener);
    }

}
```

**Reward1.java**

```
public class Reward1 extends AbstractRewardVideo {

    public Reward1(Activity activity) {
        init(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected RewardedVideoAdListener getListener() {
        return new Listener();
    }

    private class Listener implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
            //Do something...
        }
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() { loadRewardedVideoAd(); }
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {}
    }

}
```

**Reward2.java**

```
public class Reward2 extends AbstractRewardVideo {

    public Reward2(Activity activity) {
        init(activity);
    }

    @Override
    protected RewardedVideoAdListener getListener() {
        return new Listener();
    }

    private class Listener implements RewardedVideoAdListener {
        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
            //Do something...
        }
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() { loadRewardedVideoAd(); }
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {}
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {}
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Reward1 reward1;
    Reward2 reward2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        reward1 = new Reward1(this);
        reward2 = new Reward1(this);
        ...
        reward1.showVideo();
        ...
        reward2.showVideo();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    MobileAds.initialize ( this, "ca-app-pub-4761500786576152~8215465788" );

    RewardedVideoAd mAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(Video_Ad.this);

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {

}

@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

}
```